# Append Object property to RestEasy InputStream containerRequestContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, resteasy

I'm trying to add the principal id to every incoming request as part of the body. This is the code I am using:

```
        InputStream in = containerRequestContext.getEntityStream();
        String jsonRequestString = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
        JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(jsonRequestString);
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(parser);

        ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).put(PRINCIPAL_ID, containerRequestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal().getName());

        containerRequestContext
                .setEntityStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode), encoding));
```

This is my resource:

```
@POST
@Path("/service")
@RolesAllowed(USER_ROLE)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myService(String principalId, String input){
    // do stuff
}
```

When request hits the resource, I can see the new json string being bind on principalId argument e.g.

```
principalId = {"principalId": "id", "input":"input"}
```

is there a way to bind each property to the respective argument?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

- write interceptor (with AspectJ, for instance) which handle all your endpoints and populates `principalId` to your method's parameter or POJO.
- write a [servlet filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html). This option is required to read the same request twice. The first read will occur in the filter with your following preprocessing and the second one in the Spring servlet.